# Input String and int in the same line

Tags: java, output, user-input

How can I input a `String` and an `int` in the same line? Then I want to proceed it to get the largest number from int that I already input: 
Here is the code I have written so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NamaNilaiMaksimum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name[] = new String[6];
        int number[] = new int[6];
        int max = 0, largest = 0;
        int as = 5;

        for (int x = 1; x <= as; x++) {
            System.out.print(" Name & number : ");
            name[x] = in.nextLine();
            number[x] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int x = 1; x <= as; x++) {
            if (number[x] > largest) {
                largest = number[x];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result = " + largest);
    }
}
```

There's an error when I input the others name and number.

I expect the output will be like this

> Name & Number : John 45
>   Name & Number : Paul 30
>   Name & Number : Andy 25
>
> Result: John 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String InputValue;
    String name[] = new String[6];
    int number[] = new int[6];
    String LargeName = "";
    int largest = 0;
    int as = 5;

    for (int x = 1; x <= as; x++) {
        System.out.print(" Name & number : ");
        InputValue = in.nextLine();
        String[] Value = InputValue.split(" ");
        name[x] = Value[0];
        number[x] = Integer.parseInt(Value[1]);
    }

    for (int x = 1; x < number.length; x++) {
        if (number[x] > largest) {
            largest = number[x];
            LargeName = name[x];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result = " + LargeName + " " + largest);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: What is the point in using `nextLine` if you split the input with `" "`?

Comment: whie "nextLine" method returns the line that was skipped, split is storing the input values into two different arrays. hope this answers your question

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question, because I still don't know why you prefer this approach instead of using `next` and then `nextInt`. When you already know that `" "` is your delimiter, then let `Scanner`handle the "splitting".

Comment: Thanks . This really helps

Comment: @nanang please mark the answer correct, if it works. Thank you :)

Comment: Using next() will only return what comes before a space. nextLine() automatically moves the scanner down after returning the current line. i thought using next() would be longer process.. @Tom

Comment: Oh you mean it would take longer to read everything until `" "` instead reading everything until `\n`? No, this is not the case. The scanner has to read everything until he finds the delimiter. He can't skip or read something faster, because he doesn't know how the content of a stream looks like, before he read it.

Comment: No, that is not what i meant. It takes more code to be written. Please feel free to share any other piece of code or alternative solutions your may have as the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: More code? Then let's compare your approach: `InputValue = in.nextLine(); String[] Value = InputValue.split(" "); name[x] = Value[0]; number[x] = Integer.parseInt(Value[1]);` with mine: `name[x] = in.next(); number[x] = in.nextInt();`.

Comment: Awesome... Share the code as an answer so people can use it... :)

Comment: Oh, no need. Feel free to add it in your answer so it contains both approaches :).

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print(" Name & number : ");
/*
    Get the input value "name and age" separated with space " " and splite it.
    1st part is name and second part is the age as tring format!
*/
String[] Value = in.nextLine().split(" ");
name[x] = Value[0];
// Convert age with string format to int.
number[x] = Integer.parseInt(Value[1]);
```